# cakephp - getting joins correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm a bit of a newbie and I'm having trouble getting my cakephp query correct.

I have a users table and users hasmany rotas. The rotas table looks like

monday_am

monday_pm

tuesday_am

etc

and if the user is due to be in on monday_pm for example, then that field will have 1. Otherwise 0.

I want to get all the users who belong to a particular room, have deregistered=0 and - and this is where I'm having the problem - who have a rota where (for example) tuesday_am = 1

So I have the code:

```
$options['conditions'] = array('User.room_id'=>$room_id, 'User.deregistered'=>0, 'User.request'=>0);

$options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'rotas',
                  'alias' => 'rota',
                  'type' => 'INNER',
                  'conditions' => array('rota.'.$todaysDay.'_'.$amPm => 1)
                    )
                );

$usersToday = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

If I don't try the join then I get a nice small list of users like I expect. If I try the join I get 100s of results which are mostly duplicates!

How can I get just one record of a user who has the required conditions in the Users table as well as the Rotas table, and how come doing the join as I have causes so many results?!?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to define your hasMany relationship in your models? If you do that you can just add conditions for the related model and cake does the join for you. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: Do you mean like $options['conditions'] = array('User.room_id'=>$room_id, 'User.deregistered'=>0, 'User.request'=>0, 'rota.'.$todaysDay.'_'.$amPm => 1); because that didn't work. according to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables hasmany relationships require a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column in your rota table called user_id, you can make your Rota model like this:

```
class Rota extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

Then in your controller, you can query the Rotas and get the user from it.

```
$users = $this->Rota->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('DISTINCT (User.id)' /* add more fields for selection */ ), 
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.room_id'=>$room_id,
        'User.deregistered'=>0,
        'User.request'=>0,
        'Rota.'.$todaysDay.'_'.$amPm => 1
    )
));
```

Comment: Hi Jage, thanks for that, it seems to work perfectly! Although I hadthe belongs to relationship set up, I never thought of trying it like $this->Rota